# What is the matlab's rgb2ycbcr formula?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rgb, yuv

What is the matlab's rgb2ycbcr formula?Which standarts are using for this

Comment: Did you put some effort on that formula?

Answer (score 5):

The function [RGB2YCBCR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html) is part of Image Processing Toolbox.

Have you looked at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html). It's referring Poynton, C. A.A Technical Introduction to Digital Video. The same reference as in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr).

If you have the toolbox you can also look at the code how the function is implemented with `edit rgb2ycbcr` (if it does not use mex).

Comment: ITU-R BT.601 conversion vs ITU-R BT.709 conversion  which one?

Comment: See reference [2] in the doc: Rec. **ITU-R BT.601-5**, Studio Encoding Parameters of Digital Television for Standard 4:3 and Wide-screen 16:9 Aspect Ratios, (1982-1986-1990-1992-1994-1995), Section 3.5.